# Spin of quasi-particles in a Fermi Liquid à la Landau

Tags: fermi-liquids

I'm having troubles with understanding the motivation underlying the fact that a quasi-particle in a Fermi liquid à la Landau alway has spin 1/2. In section 1.1 of Landau's Theoretical Physics, volume IX, the motivation is given as follows (Pergamon Press, 1981):

> The statement that a quasi-particle has spin essentially expresses the fact that this degeneracy exists. In this sense we can say that the spin of the quasi-particles in a spectrum of the type considered [à la Landau, given that the liquid is isotropic and homogeneous, non-ferromagnetic and not placed in an external magnetic field, etc.] is always 1/2, whatever the spin of the actual particles in the liquid. For with any spin $s$ other than 1/2 [... there would be] a splitting of the (2s+1)-fold degenerate levels into 1/2(2s+1) doubly degenerate levels. In other words, 1/2(2s+1) different branches of the function $\varepsilon(\vec{p})$ would appear, each corresponding to quasi-particles with spin 1/2.

Here $\varepsilon(\vec{p})$ is the dispersion relation of a quasi-particle in the liquid (given as a functional of the quasi-particles' distribution function $n(\vec{p})$).

Does the characterization of quasi-particles as spin 1/2 degrees of freedom (instead of higher half-integer values) affect at all the thermodynamic properties of the liquid, other than the normalization of $n(\vec{p})$ (of course, in the absence of an external magnetic field)? Can anyone elaborate on Landau's statement?